# Importing MongoClient results in pkFactory error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a simple app.js file as such:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
// import session from 'express-session';
// import path from 'path';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb/lib';
// import { readdirSync } from 'fs';
// import { connectDatabase } from './config/database.mjs';
// import connectRedis from './config/redis.js';

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

As soon as I uncomment the MongoClient import, I receive the following error:

```
pkFactory: db.options?.pkFactory ?? utils_1.DEFAULT_PK_FACTORY,
```

I am following the guide from mongodb.com on how to connect with their native driver using nodejs.

Node version: v18.12.1

NPM version: 8.19.12

mongodb: ^5.7.0

Comment: There are a bunch of questions matching this exact error message here on SO, have you taken a look at them?

Comment: @user20042973 Yes I have... this is why I am coming with this thread. None have meaningful replies or working answers, most are for mongoose too.

Nonetheless as I am trying to figure out the issue, I think it might be related to using imports vs required. Not fully sure though.